# Cookie wrapper in MVC4 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, wrapper

I'd like to create a cookie wrapper in my application to help support a DRY approach to coding  common cookie methods, provide intellisense for cookie-type properties (keys), and protect against typo-errors when working with cookies from multiple classes and namespaces.

The best structure for this (that I can think of) is to apply a base class like such:

```
abstract class CookieBase{
   protected HttpRequestBase request;
   protected HttpCookie cookie;
   protected string name;

   public HttpCookie Cookie { }

   public string Name { get; }

   public HttpCookie Get(){ ... }

   protected string GetValue(string key){ ... }

   public bool IsSet(){ ... }

   protected void SetValue(string key, string value){ ... }
}
```

Then for each cookie-type that inherits the base class define properties for each key that should be stored in the HttpCookie, and define a constructor that accepts the Request object as a parameter and instantiates the Cookie property of the base class.

Any ideas on how I might improve this design, or suggestions to alternative approaches to attaining the goals I stated at the start of this post?

Comment: This is more a format for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I've moved this post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30251/cookie-wrapper-in-mvc4-c